# Trigger selection event for Arcgis Operations Dashboard with js

Tags: javascript, arcgis-portal, operations-dashboard

I have several dashboards which i want to display within the same webpage.
each dashboard is loaded within an iframe and switching between them is done with basic js and css.
they are all manipulated with the same dropdown category selector using the same layer to help users select the data they want to see.

what i want to do is carry the selection over between all the dashboards, meaning that when the user want to see the indicators for city **A** he could select it in dashboard 1, and dashboards 2,3,4 and 5 will show the data for city **A** too.

I tried triggering `click` and `focus` events for the `<a class="side-nav-link"></a>` elements, as well as removign and adding the `is-active` and `highlight` classes for them like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082316/how-to-set-active-class-to-nav-menu-from-twitter-bootstrap).

I also tried setting the values in the `input` and the `value-container` divs.

I realise that `<a>` shouldnt be activated by `click` events so I tried using the advice from [here](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-simulate-a-click-event-with-javascript/).

It seems like i'm missing an event that could be triggered, but i can't find any more advice about how make this selection.

## Clarification

I know how to access the elements within the `<ifram>`, i'm looking for a way to create a slection.
here's a codepen with an example dashboard within an iframe and the way to access the elements within the dashboard document.
https://codepen.io/bogind/pen/mYOpKB

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with reload of `iframe` content each time filter is changed, you can use URL parameters to do filtering in all content dashboards. Reference below:

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/dashboards/create-and-share/url-parameters.htm

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/dashboards/create-and-share/configuring-actions-on-url-parameters.htm